# Multiple Inputs To Make An Alert Output

Tags: javascript

I'm having some trouble with a website I'm doing for my GCSE Coursework - I was hoping someone could help me? I need to make around 4 input boxes and then correlate them to make a user custom alert. Confusing stuff I know; here, let me make some bad pseudocode:

```
user INPUT box for game ID
user INPUT box for name
user INPUT box for start day of reservation

IF game ID > 8 || < 1
    PRINT error message
ELIF game ID > 1 && < 8
    PRINT corresponding game ID AND user name AND start date in an alert box
```

Or, here's some scruffy Python code:

```
x = input("Game ID: ")
y = input("Name: ")
z = input("Start Day of Reservation: ")

if (x > 8 && < 1):
    print("Invalid Input")
elif x == 1:
    print("Thank you, " + y + "for renting " + x + " from " + z")
#repeats elif code from 1-8 for individual game names.
```

Can anyone help? Thanks :)

Comment: Look into [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), the [input element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement), and [alert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert). FYI using alerts for user notifications is annoying.

Comment: @JamieCalver where'd you disappear to?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking something like this:

```js
function handleForm() {
  var gameId, gameName, startDate;
  gameId = document.getElementById("gameId").value;
  gameName = document.getElementById("gameName").value;
  startDate = document.getElementById("startDate").value;
  if (gameId > 8 || gameId < 1) {
    alert("Error!");
  } else {
    alert(gameId + " " + gameName + " " + startDate);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="gameId" placeholder="ID">
<input type="text" id="gameName" placeholder="Name">
<input type="date" id="startDate" placeholder="Start date">
<button onclick="handleForm()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: hey there! thanks, this is looking promising! I have one problem though... Am I being stupid or not but I've put your code into mine and put the `script` tags in but nothing comes up, a blank page? Could you help? Thanks again! :)

Comment: Could you paste your code to somewhere. It's easier to see that way what's wrong in there.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you need something like this...

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            d = document;

            function verifyData(i){
               var gameid = d.getElementById('gameid_' + i).value,
                name = d.getElementById('name_' + i).value,
                date = d.getElementById('date_' + i).value;

                if (i >= 1 || i <= 8){
                    if (gameid && name && date) alert('Thank you, ' + name + ', for renting ' + gameid + ' from ' + date);
                    else alert('All fields are required for verification.');
                } else alert('Invalid Row.');
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="gameid_1" placeholder="Game ID" /><input id="name_1" placeholder="Game ID" /><input id="date_1" placeholder="Date" /><input onclick="verifyData(1);" type="button" value="Verify" /><br />

        <input id="gameid_2" placeholder="Game ID" /><input id="name_2" placeholder="Game ID" /><input id="date_2" placeholder="Date" /><input onclick="verifyData(2);" type="button" value="Verify" /><br />

        <input id="gameid_3" placeholder="Game ID" /><input id="name_3" placeholder="Game ID" /><input id="date_3" placeholder="Date" /><input onclick="verifyData(3);" type="button" value="Verify" /><br />

        <input id="gameid_4" placeholder="Game ID" /><input id="name_4" placeholder="Game ID" /><input id="date_4" placeholder="Date" /><input onclick="verifyData(4);" type="button" value="Verify" /><br />

        <input id="gameid_5" placeholder="Game ID" /><input id="name_5" placeholder="Game ID" /><input id="date_5" placeholder="Date" /><input onclick="verifyData(5);" type="button" value="Verify" /><br />

        <input id="gameid_6" placeholder="Game ID" /><input id="name_6" placeholder="Game ID" /><input id="date_6" placeholder="Date" /><input onclick="verifyData(6);" type="button" value="Verify" /><br />

        <input id="gameid_7" placeholder="Game ID" /><input id="name_7" placeholder="Game ID" /><input id="date_7" placeholder="Date" /><input onclick="verifyData(7);" type="button" value="Verify" /><br />

        <input id="gameid_8" placeholder="Game ID" /><input id="name_8" placeholder="Game ID" /><input id="date_8" placeholder="Date" /><input onclick="verifyData(8);" type="button" value="Verify" /><br />
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/ytpwkotd/1/